# I'm not getting any event from 'fromEvent( window, 'scroll' )'l

Tags: angular

I have 2 question

1. is it a good approach to use 'window' and 'fromEvent'

   --> I saw some explnation that you should not directly access dom.
2. I'm not getting any event 'fromEvent(window, 'scroll');

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    const source = fromEvent(window, 'scroll');
    const example = source.pipe(map(event => 'Event time: ${event.timeStamp}'));
    example.subscribe( val => console.log(val) );
  }
}
```

This is also imported

When i scroll, This is not working at all ( not getting any console output )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad..

in css, these properties prevent 'scroll event'

when i disabled these properties, 'scroll event' fired properly

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;

}
```

but i'm still curious about number 1 question